# Return to front of paginated UIScrollView from first page?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, carousel

I'm using a `UIScrollView` to make a web-style carousel with some pages detailing how my app works, and I'm using an `NSTimer` to flip between the pages (by moving the content offset).

I'm a little stumped as to how I can make the last page (the far right of the scroll view) transition to the left, as if it'd cycled back to the first page, so cycling like so:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3
```

At present I'm just telling it to offset back to position 1 after position 3, but obviously this is achieved by moving left, back through postiion 2, as opposed to continuing on right and discovering position 1 again.

I can't use a Page View Controller here, since I don't have enough fine-grain control over what happens on a per-page basis, the speed of the transition between those pages, other animations, etc., so I really definitely need to use the `UIScrollView`, and find a way to swipe forwards from page 3 and have page 1 return.

Any ideas? How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to take a look in [official apple example of infinite scroll view](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011102-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)
or use [iCarousel control](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)
If you don't want to do this you should add your views like this [1 2 3 1] and after sweaping to last view call this method:

```
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, width , height) animated:NO];
```